# Realloc makes dynamic-array NULL

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays, realloc, calloc

So first I start with a `calloc` of 365/366 slots then I put a whole year there then my idea was when the user enters a different year it will reallocate more memory and enter the new year in the dynamic array, the problem is when I try to reallocate the  array, it doesn't work and puts me the whole array `NULL`
Does someone knows what's causing this?

This is the line of code I'm using:

```
int old_size = est->agenda[i].sized, newsize = old_size + 365;
est->agenda[i].d = (CALENDER_DAY*) realloc(est->agenda[i].d, newsize * sizeof(CALENDER_DAY));
est->agenda[i].sized = newsize;
```

Comment: If `realloc` returns NULL, then call `perror` to find out *why* it failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`realloc` returns `NULL` when it cannot satisfy the request - the memory is still allocated and undisturbed, but you overwrote your only reference to it.

*Always* assign the result of `realloc` to a temporary pointer variable and check for `NULL` *before* updating the target pointer and the size:

```
/**
 * DON'T cast the result of malloc, calloc, or realloc in C.  It's unnecessary
 * and in older versions could suppress a useful diagnostic. 
 *
 * sizeof *tmp == sizeof (CALENDAR_DAY) - it's a little easier to read and maintain.
 */
CALENDAR_DAY *tmp = realloc( est->agenda[i].d, (oldsize + 365) * sizeof *tmp ); 
if ( tmp )
{
  est->agenda[i].d = tmp;
  oldsize = oldsize + 365;
}
else
{
  // realloc could not satisfy the request, handle as appropriate
}
```

This way you do not lose your reference to the already-allocated memory.

Unfortunately, `realloc` is not required to set `errno` in the event of a failure, so it may be difficult to troubleshoot *why* the `realloc` call failed.  But at least this way you can recover.